# Grasping Ruby chef block

Tags: ruby

I am trying to figure out how this block works

```
htpasswd "/etc/nginx/htpassword" do
  user "foo"
  password "bar"
end
```

I see this style of code a lot in Chef cookbooks.
I am very new to ruby, like super new, but have a lot of experience in other languages.

I think I have worked out that htpasswd is a proc? But what is stumping me is how the filename is being used, and how the assignment is working `user "foo"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimal implementation of the same syntax, pretty typical for Ruby configuration management.

The key point here is that `htpassword` is a method that accepts two parameters - a string and a block. Blocks in Ruby capture the scope they are defined in (syntax scope), so you use `instance_eval` inside the configurator to run the block inside its scope instead, which has the `user` and `password` methods defined, which are trivial setters. Configurators can't use the more intuitive `user = "foo"` syntax because that would just declare a local variable inside the block.

```
class Configurator
  def user(username)
    @user=username
  end

  def htpassword(filename, &block)
    @filename=filename
    instance_eval(&block)
  end

  def run
    puts "User = #{@user}, filename = #{@filename}"
  end
end




c=Configurator.new

c.htpassword "thefilename" do
  user "theuser"
end

c.run
#>User = theuser, filename = thefilename
```

Comment: Thanks that was a great explanation and really cleared things up. Before I award best answer, could you explain why the params are not comma separated?

Comment: If the last parameter in a method is a block, it can be written right after the method call. So if you had two arguments before the block, it would be `htpassword "foo", "bar" do`, or with the optional parens - `htpassword("foo", "bar") do`

Comment: Hmmm very interesting. Ruby is a whimsical beast. Enjoy the best answer :)